# Fade in elements on scroll / page load

Tags: jquery

I am working on a site where I want the content to fade up and in on scroll to it being in the viewport. I have the code below working well on scroll - but would like to enhance it in 2 ways which I can't seem to work out how to acheive what I want...

Firstly, I want this function to fire on page load so if the page is scrolled on load - the items that are in view should fade and animate into view - currently they dont.

Secondly - Is there a way to finese this code a little to specifiy the % of the element that needs to be in view before the animate and fade in animation occurs?

```
function fadeInDivsOScrollToo() {
$('.fade-in').each(function() {
    var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element) && !$(this).hasClass('is-visible')) {
        $(this).addClass('is-visible');
    }
});

}
$(window).on('load', function(){ fadeInDivsOScrollToo(); });
$(window).on('scroll', function(){ fadeInDivsOScrollToo(); });
$(window).on('resize', function(){ fadeInDivsOScrollToo(); });
```

with CSS:

```
.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20vh);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease-out, transform 1.2s ease-out;
  will-change: opacity, visibility;
}

.fade-in.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry - ended up binning this approach and using Waypoints instead.